# Ultrabook with good cooling

Tags: laptop, processor, cooling, high-end, intel

I am looking for a ultrabook. (13-14" up to about 1.5kg) I would like to have 32GB RAM and high end ULV processor like for example i7-8650U or i7-8550U. I also would like to have 4x PCIe Thunderbolt and 4GT/s OPI which seems to be standard for this type of configuration. Additionally if possible would be nice to have metal body. I want to run Windows 10 OS on it.

The problem I am facing is that the cooling is not sufficient, on all I was able to find, and as a result CPU temperature goes up to 100 Celsius and at this point thermal protection kicks in and speed of CPU is reduced significantly for short period of time to prevent overheating. Are there any ultrabooks with good cooling or is that just standard to design them the way so they overheat on heavy load?

Comment: What kind of load? If the load is that much, you're gonna need something with more active cooling and its not gonna be an ultrabook.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Various loads related to computer science. It requires 100% of CPU for short amounts of time like 10-30 min. The CPU is capable of delivering what I require, so if it was cooled enough I know that it would be sufficient. I do not want thermal throttling as it makes my calculations inaccurate (temperature affects the results - I do not want that)

Comment: Well, they are kinda designed that way....Gonna have to go bigger than an ultrabook so you get active cooling (and no throttling).